# Get Windows DisplayLanguage with Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying to get Windows Display Language setting via powershell. I tried Get-WinUserLanguageList but this returns the list of all languages. Get-WinSystemLocale and Get-Culture are also not the ones that i am looking for. Is there a way to get current display language?

What i am looking for is this:

[image: Language settings]

Comment: Why are Get-WinSystemLocele and Get-Culture not what you are looking for?

Comment: Culture returns something for syntax settings and stuff and system local depends to my server. All three are different values for my computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```bsh
(Get-UICulture).Name
```

or

```bsh
$PSUICulture
```

Official Document [Get-UICulture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-uiculture?view=powershell-7)

Comment: Thank you, but this one doesn't work on remote session. It keeps returning my own computer's display setting, not the remote one's.

Comment: Thank you, I have created a new question for remote computer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61681766/get-windows-displaylanguage-with-powershell-on-remote-desktop