# Get Windows DisplayLanguage with Powershell on Remote Desktop

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying to get Windows Display Language setting via powershell on **remote computer**. I tried Get-WinUserLanguageList but this returns the list of all languages. Get-WinSystemLocale and Get-Culture are also not the ones that i am looking for because Culture returns something for syntax settings and stuff and system local depends to my server. All three are different values for remote desktop. Is there a way to get current display language of remote desktop?

What i am looking for is this setting of remote computer:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The language you see there is the first one in the list from `Get-WinUserLanguageList`.

```bsh
PS C:\> (Get-WinUserLanguageList).LocalizedName
Russian
English (United States)
```

[image: language_settings]

When I change the order of the list, and set English first, it reverses the order in PowerShell.

```bsh
PS C:\> Set-WinUserLanguageList -LanguageList en-US,ru

Confirm
Continue with this operation?
[Y] Yes  [N] No  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"): Y
PS C:\> (Get-WinUserLanguageList).LocalizedName
English (United States)
Russian
```

[image: updatedlanguage]

So to get the current language, you merely have to call the first object in that list.

```bsh
(Get-WinUserLanguageList)[0].LocalizedName
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. `(Get-WinUserLanguageList)[0].LocalizedName` returns "English (United Kingdom)" when in fact it's "English (United States)" the one configured as Windows Display. That one is in position `1` actually.

Comment: Your Preferred Languages in the same part of the settings are probably in a different order.

Answer (score 4):

[Ash's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61682322/45375) is the **best solution for machines running Windows 8 or above / Windows Server 2012 R2 or above**.

---

If you still need to run remotely on a **Windows 7 / Windows Server 2012** machine:

```
(Get-ItemProperty 'HKCU:\Control Panel\Desktop' PreferredUILanguages).PreferredUILanguages[0]
```

---

**Background information**:

In *local* execution, the simplest solution is to use `$PSUICulture` (returns a string with the language name, such as `en-US`) or `Get-UICulture` (returns a `[cultureinfo]` object), as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61676489/45375).

However, this *doesn't* work when you use PowerShell *remoting* (which is why the above solution / Ash's solution is necessary):

```
# Does NOT return the target user's display language.
# Seemingly always returns the OS installation language.
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $someComputer { $PSUICulture }
```

I'm unclear on the exact reasons, but it may be related to the fact that remotely executed PowerShell code runs in an invisible window station that is distinct from the interactive desktop.